# org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android

Получаю с сервера несколько объектов, а по мимо их еще и эту ошибку, сами объекты почему не выводятся...

Ошибка

```
E/Fail 3: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Код запроса

```
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class zaprosJur extends Thread
{
    String lK;

    String time1;
    String time2;

    String rashodPF1;
    String rashodPF2;

    String rashodHg1;
    String rashodHg2;

    String razSm;

    String verhTolk1;
    String verhTolk2;

    String nizTolk1;
    String nizTolk2;

    String temper1;
    String temper2;

    String ppf1;
    String npf1;
    String ppf2;
    String npf2;

    String davTwoVkl1;
    String davTwoVikl1;

    String davTwoVkl2;
    String davTwoVikl2;

    String davThreeVkl1;
    String davThreeVikl1;

    String davThreeVkl2;
    String davThreeVikl2;

    String davMult1;
    String davMult2;

    String speedOne1;
    String speedOne2;

    String speedTwo1;
    String speedTwo2;

    String start11;
    String start12;
    String start21;
    String start22;

    String aktyal1;
    String aktyal2;

    String aydit1;
    String aydit2;

    String akt;

    String model;

    String fio;

    String smena;

    String data;

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String line = null;

    public void run()
    {
        // создаем лист для отправки запросов
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        // один параметр, если нужно два и более просто добовляем также
        boolean Lk = nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lk", this.lK));
        boolean Smena = nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Smena", this.smena));
        boolean Data = nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Data", this.data));
        //  подключаемся к php запросу и отправляем в него id
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http:****.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        }

        // получаем ответ от php запроса в формате json
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success" + result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }
        // обрабатываем полученный json
        try
        {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            rashodPF1 = (json_data.optString("RashodPF1"));
            rashodPF2 = (json_data.optString("RashodPF2"));

            model = (json_data.optString("Model"));

            time1 = (json_data.optString("Time1"));
            time2 = (json_data.optString("Time2"));

            rashodHg1 = (json_data.optString("RashodHg1"));
            rashodHg2 = (json_data.optString("RashodHg2"));

            razSm = (json_data.optString("RazSm"));

            verhTolk1 = (json_data.optString("VerhTolk1"));
            verhTolk2 = (json_data.optString("VerhTolk2"));

            nizTolk1 = (json_data.optString("NizTolk1"));
            nizTolk2 = (json_data.optString("NizTolk2"));

            temper1 = (json_data.optString("Temper1"));
            temper2 = (json_data.optString("Temper2"));

            ppf1 = (json_data.optString("PPF1"));
            npf1 = (json_data.optString("NPF1"));
            ppf2 = (json_data.optString("PPF2"));
            npf2 = (json_data.optString("NPF2"));

            davTwoVkl1 = (json_data.optString("DavTwoVkl1"));
            davTwoVikl1 = (json_data.optString("DavTwoVikl1"));

            davTwoVkl2 = (json_data.optString("DavTwoVkl2"));
            davTwoVikl2 = (json_data.optString("DavTwoVikl2"));

            davThreeVkl1 = (json_data.optString("DavThreeVkl1"));
            davThreeVikl1 = (json_data.optString("DavThreeVikl1"));

            davThreeVkl2 = (json_data.optString("DavThreeVkl2"));
            davThreeVikl2 = (json_data.optString("DavThreeVikl2"));

            davMult1 = (json_data.optString("DavMult1"));
            davMult2 = (json_data.optString("DavMult2"));

            speedOne1 = (json_data.optString("SpeedOne1"));
            speedOne2 = (json_data.optString("SpeedOne2"));

            speedTwo1 = (json_data.optString("SpeedTwo1"));
            speedTwo2 = (json_data.optString("SpeedTwo2"));

            start11 = (json_data.optString("Start11"));
            start12 = (json_data.optString("Start12"));
            start21 = (json_data.optString("Start21"));
            start22 = (json_data.optString("Start22"));

            aktyal1 = (json_data.optString("Aktyal1"));
            aktyal2 = (json_data.optString("Aktyal2"));

            aydit1 = (json_data.optString("Aydit1"));
            aydit2 = (json_data.optString("Aydit2"));

            akt = (json_data.optString("Akt"));

            fio = (json_data.optString("Fio"));

            Log.e("pass 3", lK);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          //  String err = (e.getMessage() == null)?"Connection failed":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("Fail 3 ", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void start(String lks, String smenas, String datas)
    {
        this.lK = lks;
        this.smena = smenas;
        this.data = datas;
        this.start();
    }

    public String resrashodPF1()
    {
        return rashodPF1;
    }

    public String resrashodHg1() {
        return rashodHg1;
    }

    public String resrazSm() {
        return razSm;
    }

    public String resverhTolk1() {
        return verhTolk1;
    }

    public String resverhTolk2() {
        return verhTolk2;
    }

    public String restemper1() {
        return temper1;
    }

    public String resppf1() {
        return ppf1;
    }

    public String resnpf1() {
        return npf1;
    }

    public String resdavTwoVkl1() {
        return davTwoVkl1;
    }

    public String resdavTwoVikl1() {
        return davTwoVikl1;
    }

    public String resdavThreeVkl1() {
        return davThreeVkl1;
    }

    public String resdavThreeVikl1() {
        return davThreeVikl1;
    }

    public String resdavMult1() {
        return davMult1;
    }

    public String resspeedOne1() {
        return speedOne1;
    }

    public String resspeedTwo1() {
        return speedTwo1;
    }

    public String resstart11() {
        return start11;
    }

    public String resstart12() {
        return start12;
    }

    public String resaktyal1() {
        return aktyal1;
    }

    public String resaydit1() {
        return aydit1;
    }

    public String resrashodPF2() {
        return  rashodPF2;
    }

    public String resrashodHg2() {
        return rashodHg2;
    }

    public String resnizTolk1() {
        return nizTolk1;
    }

    public String resnizTolk2() {
        return nizTolk2;
    }

    public String restemper2() {
        return temper2;
    }

    public String resppf2() {
        return ppf2;
    }

    public String resnpf2() {
        return npf2;
    }

    public String resdavTwoVkl2() {
        return davTwoVkl2;
    }

    public String resdavTwoVikl2() {
        return davTwoVikl2;
    }

    public String resdavThreeVkl2() {
        return davThreeVkl2;
    }

    public String resdavThreeVikl2() {
        return davThreeVikl2;
    }

    public String resdavMult2() {
        return davMult2;
    }

    public String resspeedOne2() {
        return  speedOne2;
    }

    public String resspeedTwo2() {
        return speedTwo2;
    }

    public String resstart21() {
        return start21;
    }

    public String resstart22() {
        return start22;
    }

    public String resaktyal2() {
        return aktyal2;
    }

    public String resaydit2() {
        return aydit2;
    }

    public String restime1()
    {
        return time1;
    }

    public String restime2()
    {
        return time2;
    }

    public String resmodel()
    {
        return model;
    }

    public String resfio()
    {
        return fio;
    }

    public String resakt()
    {
        return akt;
    }
}
```

То что приходит с сервера

```
{"Akt":"45","Model":"Base 500","Time1":"10:50:55","RashodPF1":"2","RashodHg1":"648","RazSm":"9504","VerhTolk1":"6405","NizTolk1":"8405","Temper1":"910","PPF1":"49","NPF1":"272","DavTwoVkl1":"5","DavTwoVikl1":"505","DavThreeVkl1":"508","DavThreeVikl1":"768","DavMult1":"508","SpeedOne1":"576","SpeedTwo1":"850","Start11":"85","Start12":"576","Aktyal1":"\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0442","Aydit1":"\u0421\u043e\u043e\u0442","Time2":"10:50:55","RashodPF2":"9","RashodHg2":"6610","VerhTolk2":"404","NizTolk2":"406","Temper2":"490","PPF2":"91","NPF2":"268","DavTwoVkl2":"575","DavTwoVikl2":"550","DavThreeVkl2":"68","DavThreeVikl2":"868","DavMult2":"276","SpeedOne2":"590","SpeedTwo2":"89","Start21":"720","Start22":"246","Aktyal2":"\u041d\u0435 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442","Aydit2":" \u041d\u0435 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442"}
```

Comment: Логируйте строку перед тем как скормить `new JSONObject(result)` - очевидно что у вас она осталось пустой.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, а как это сделать? Не совсем понимаю про что вы. До этого много где применял подобный запрос, точь в точь и не разу такого не было в логах

Comment: А если перед этим в result вручную затолкать строку без вот этого `\u041d\u0435 \u0441\u043e\u043e\u0442`

Comment: @DrMcSheen, это тоже интересный момент, почти во все строки приходят числа, и только в 4 строки получаю текст, отображается то нормально, но в логах вот так. Не особо понимаю как перед result сроку "затолкать", подскажите?

Comment: Вы показали json, который **должен** приходить, или который **реально** приходит при ошибке? Ошибка говорит, что в конструктор `JSONObject` передана строка, начинающаяся с `"null"`

Comment: Надо перестать применять данный запрос и воспользоваться библиотеками. retrofit + gson спасут вас от ненужного дебага.

Comment: @woesss, он и должен приходить, но основная проблема в том, что не выводится в строки и выдает указанную ошибку

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо за совет, есть какой нибудь пример или приблизительные варианты?

Comment: См здесь https://square.github.io/retrofit/ 
И здесь пример https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleService.java

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо, нашел в чем проблема, в php криво отрабатывалось